# Access ModelParent on ItemCollection when using CollectionChang‌​ed event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Currently I'm scrolling my `DataGrid`'s to the bottom when adding new Items to it, like this:

```
// responses is an ObservableCollection where I add the content from http responses
responses.Add(content);
// dataGrid.ItemsSource is binded to responses
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(content);
```

My idea is now to move the logic for scrolling the `DataGrid` to the bottom in the method that adds items to the collection to an event handler:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)DataGrid.Items).CollectionChang‌​ed += CollectionChangedEventHandler;

private void CollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemCollection = sender as ItemCollection;

    // How to access ModelParent here?
}
```

If I debug my code I can see that the `itemCollection` object has the property `ModelParent` on it which seems to be the correct `DataGrid`. However, I can't access it, not even with reflection:

```
var dataGrid = itemCollection.GetType().GetProperty("ModelParent").GetValue(itemCollection);
```

`itemCollection.GetType().GetProperty("ModelParent")` just returns `null`. Is it possible to access the `DataGrid` from inside the event handler via `sender` (I have multiple DataGrids that I want to use the same event handler for) or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: I'm sure to you, the above all makes perfect sense. But, without a [mcve] to illustrate the question, there are way too many assumptions we have to make about the code, and far too many possibilities in terms of answers. Please provide said [mcve] and explain in more detail what you've tried, why it didn't work, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access the `DataGrid` from inside the event handler via `sender` or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

No. The sender argument refers to the `ItemCollection` or `ObservableCollection<T>` instance that raised the `CollectionChanged` event. This collection has no reference to the `DataGrid` control that happens to bind to the collection and display it in the UI.

You need to find another approach of doing whatever you are trying to do. Trying to access a `DataGrid` in the `CollectionChanged` event handler for an `ObservableCollection<T>` is not a good idea.